# laravel 4 installation problems

Tags: git, terminal, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

i have been struggling with this for about 20 hours now and i cannot move forward. I am hopeless and tired from all that searching. Dont know where else should i try to find the solution. At the begining i should probably say that i am not a terminal/composer/git user. I am trying to install the laravel 4 framework. I have been googling a lot and found some tutorials, some of the even here on stackoverflow but noting really helped me.

I have the basic github master zip package extracted at my localhost. I have installed composer i have also installed git on my local machine. I have uncommented the php.ini "`extension=php_openssl.dll`".
Like i said i dont use terminal regulary but i manage to cd into my extracted laravel folder and i have run "`composer install`" command which starts the installation. But soon i get error.

```
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://nodeload.github.com/doctrine/lexer/zip/bc0e1f0cc285127a38c6c8ea
  88bc5dba2fd53e94" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Unab
  le to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when yo
  u configured PHP?
```

Which should be fixed by that change i made in php.ini file. Of course i have restart the server but i still get this error. I have also reinstalled wamp to the newer version so right now i am using php 5.4.3

When i try to open my laravel public i get this error.

```
( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Warning: require(C:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  247400  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0011  252392  require( 'C:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php' ) ..\index.php:21

( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  247400  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0011  252392  require( 'C:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php' ) ..\index.php:21
```

Which is i believe beacuse its just not complete since composer does not downloaded all the dependencies. I dont know what esle to say if you need more info just say so. Thank you for any help. And at last i am sorry for my poor english its my secondary language.

---

UPDATE:

So i was searching some more and found [this article](http://tisuchi.wordpress.com/2013/04/30/install-laravel-4-in-windows/). I was missing this step: `START > MY COMPUTER > PROPERTIES > ADVANCED > ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES > double click on PATH from SYSTEM VARIABLES > now copy the path address of git installer (normally in windows it’s by default address is C:\Program Files\Git\bin)`
After that it gone further, asked for my github acc because it says that its private depo. So i have created one today and used it. Then it throws me this error.

```
      [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://api.github.com/authorizations" file could not be downloaded: U
  nable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you co
  nfigured PHP?
  failed to open stream: Invalid argument



install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-c
ustom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--opt
imize-autoloader]
```

My php.ini openssl line is uncommented and when i look at phpinfo i can see that its loaded.`openssl
OpenSSL support     enabled
OpenSSL Library Version     OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue with the php.ini file of WAMP

the php.ini used by the command line is located in the "PHP folder" and is `NOT` the same one used by the Apache server.

Find the php.ini from the `WAMP > localhost > php > bin` file (In my case C:\localhost\bin\php\php5.3.13)

And enable the `extension=php_openssl.dll`

Then it should work

Comment: Thank you for reply. I just went to say similar thing if anyone else experience this problem. After roughly 3 days of struggling with this i decided to test it in different enviroment. So i booted up my linux checked php.ini and everything went fine.
Problem was that i was editing php ini on my windows installation throught wamp context menu php.ini linik which is unfortunatelly the one in the apache/bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with me. I'm using XAMPP and there is only one php.ini in there. I think I have set everything up correctly according to the two hours of Googling I have done on the issue. I've also turned off the Firewall. This is very frustrating! My dev environment is in Windows so I really don't want to have to start messing about with Linux virtual machines.

Comment: UPDATE: Thanks for the update Ryan. I have just solved my issue by installing xampp 1.8.1 and running it from there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standalone no composer installation: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-preloaded

Note that this will not have an upgrade path and is experimental.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have the answer already however if you or anyone else is having issues installing Laravel 4 using WAMP you can use my flowcharts for a step by step installation.
https://github.com/scrfix/Laravel4x_FlowCharts

Wayne