# Install Laravel framework on WAMP

Tags: laravel-4, wamp, composer-php

I have been trying to install Laravel framework on WAMP.
I been following the steps from http://laravel.com/
and [Installing Laravel 4.1 in Windows 7 // Make .phar file globally available to windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829129/installing-laravel-4-1-in-windows-7-make-phar-file-globally-available-to-win)

When i run the command
 composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist , getting the error message 
[RuntimeException]
You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https

But i have enabled openssl  in php.ini by removing the comment sign. 
Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [laravel 4 installation problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918616/laravel-4-installation-problems)

Comment: Please check with phpinfo(); that openssl is enabled and working.

Comment: I must recommend using `laravel.phar`. Just make `php.exe` accessible to the command line, and then run `php laravel.har new` or `php laravel.har new awesome_app`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WAMPServer here is the problem:

WAMPServer's PHP CLI ( Command Line Interface ) i.e. running php.exe from command line uses a different php.ini to the one used by PHP in Apache.

Edit `\wamp\bin\php\php5.x.y\php.ini`

Activate the extensions you require the PHP CLI to have access to in the usual way i.e. remove the comment ';' from the `extension=php_xxxx.dll` line.

Answer (score 1):

Wamp uses 2 php.ini
first one that you changed from the Wamp panel and second one that located on Apache folder. 
i think on the wamp/bin/apache/bin make sure to enable openssl on both and restart the Wamp.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Laravel-Framework-in-Windows) worked for me. Hope this helps you.

- Install Laravel Framework in Windows *PHP version greater than
  5.3.7 is required.
- Download Laravel from: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/archive/master.zip.
- Extract Laravel into the www folder for WAMP.
- Download Composer from: https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe
- Enable openssl from all php.ini files
- Install Composer into the same directory php.exe is located.
- Click on WAMP icon->PHP->PHP Extensions and enable: php_openssl, php_curl, php_socket.
- Click on wamp icon->Apache->Apache Modules and enable ssl_module
- Open cmd.
- Change into the directory where you extracted Laravel e.g: cd C:\wamp\www\laravel.
- Type the command: composer install.
- Installation completed.
- Open httpd.conf file
- Add these lines after ***Include "c:/wamp/alias/*"***
  Listen 8000

  DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/laravel/public
- Open Browser and go to `localhost:8000`

Answer (score 0):

```
You follow given Only 1 step and install laravel 5 and composer in your machine
[1]Paste this in cmd : composer create-project laravel/laravel

when you run above command it will automatically install composer and laravel  

OPTIONAL:
if error your configuration does not allow connection to 
http//packages.firegento.com in cmd follow this command :  
  composer config -g secure-http false
```

Comment: This issue has been solved Years Ago. Why people keep posting answer?

Comment: But Thanks anyway